# why kernel macro for_each_cpu loop from cpu = -1 for smp?

Tags: for-loop, kernel

Why macro `for_each_cpu` loops from `cpu` equal to `-1`? It is hard to understand this definition in `include/linux/cpumask.h`:

```
249 /**
250  * for_each_cpu - iterate over every cpu in a mask
251  * @cpu: the (optionally unsigned) integer iterator
252  * @mask: the cpumask pointer
253  * 
254  * After the loop, cpu is >= nr_cpu_ids.
255  */
256 #define for_each_cpu(cpu, mask)             \
257     for ((cpu) = -1;                \
258         (cpu) = cpumask_next((cpu), (mask)),    \
259         (cpu) < nr_cpu_ids;)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "canonic" form of `for` expression:

```
for(<initialize>; <condition>; <move-to-next>)
```

the macro `for_each_cpu` uses another form:

```
for(<pre-initialize>; (<move-to-next>, <condition>); )
```

that is, its leaves the 3d argument empty but combine `<move-to-next>` and `<condition>` part into the second argument to `for` (Remember: result of the comma-operator is its right part).

This is roughly equivalent to

```
for(<pre-initialize> and <move-to-next>; <move-to-next>; <condition>)
```

that is, `move-to-next` operation is performed even **before the first iteration**.

So, `for_each_cpu` could be defined "canonically" as following:

```
#define for_each_cpu(cpu, mask)            \
 for ((cpu) = cpumask_next((-1), (mask));  \
    (cpu) = cpumask_next((cpu), (mask));   \
    (cpu) < nr_cpu_ids)
```

One of the difference with the original definition is that here `mask` is **evaluated twice** (while original definition evaluates `mask` only once).

Probably, intention to evaluate `mask` only once is a reason of a "complex" definition.